# Visual Studio Code: Can't find any module (Python)

Tags: python

I am rather new to programming. Right now, I am using vsc to code on OS X (the same error occurs in Terminal). But for whatever reason, I can't use my modules in python; I tried different ones, like pandas or numpy. I always get the same error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

I tried to update and reinstall the modules, pip, and python. Now I am out of ideas. Does anyone have an Idea on how to fix that?

I tried to import modules:
`import pandas as pd`

But got the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Comment: How did you install python ?

Comment: This is most probably duplicate question (there are quite many ModuleNotFoundError questions here and most of them have same correct answer), but anyway, just check `import sys; print(sys.executable)`. Then, run `path/to/python -m pip install pandas`. Using the *correct python path* (from sys.executable).

Comment: Have you selected the right Python interpreter? Meaning the one for which all the packages you need are installed.

Comment: Check you installed pandas in any of your virtual environment?
or you created any virtual environment and trying to access it?

Comment: Read through this entire document, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial - it should work post that.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `pip list` in your shell and see if `pandas` is printed.

If not, it means that it has not been installed. See [there](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/install.html) for instalation instructions.

See also the [VS Code doc about Python and selection of interpreters.](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python#_environments)

Comment: First of all, thanks for helping!
pandas is indeed printed

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
pip install module_name
```

in your case

```
pip install pandas
```

and then to verify if your panda is installed well you can check it by :

```
# display pandas details
pip show pandas
```

you will have an output like this :

```
Output:

    Name: pandas

    Version: 1.1.5
```

then you can import your panda library

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether you chose the correct python Interpreter?

Use shortcuts **Ctrl+Shift+P** and search for `"Python:Select Interpreter"` to check it.